# Border tag not working in around HTML5 video tag

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I want to put a red border around the video I am playing in my website. and here is my code.

```
    <div class="yotube_video">
        <video width="700" height="525" controls="controls" scrolling="no" >
            <source src="video/promo_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

and Style sheet includes

```
div.youtube_video{
border:5px solid red;}
```

Why am I not getting the border around the video. Please help. Also, is there any online help to make the video more artistic?

Thanks in advance,
aqzr

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please vote for the best answer and accept it as a answer please. By doing this, you encourage people to help others here on stackoverflow. @shriguru nayak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your HTML you wrote:

```
<div class="yotube_video">
```

Then in your CSS you wrote:

```
div.youtube_video
```

The class name in HTML and CSS should be the same. In your HTML file you forgot a "u".
It should be like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="youtube_video">
<video width="700" height="525" controls src="video/promo_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

`controls="controls"` doesn't exist. You just have to write `controls` if you want to enable them. `scrolling` doesn't exist. Then you need the tag `source` only if you provide multiple source files encoded in different formats for different browsers. In your example it shouldn't be necessary. Just using `src` is enough.

**CSS**

```
div.youtube_video{
border:5px solid red;}
```

---

Anyway since you are using the `video` tag, that is a new tag introduced in HTML5 to provide a better semantic, you could avoid using a wrapping `div` and give an id or a class directly to the `video` tag.
So your **HTML** would become like this:

```
<video class="youtube_video" width="700" height="525" controls src="video/promo_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And your **CSS** would become like this:

```
.youtube_video{
    border:5px solid red;}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8fuqY/1/)

Comment: @AspiringAqib thanks :) webdesign is a great passion of mine. Whenever i can help, i do it with pleasure. :) Also your answer was correct anyway, so still good job :)

Comment: any example of your site? i m looking for some css designer :)

Comment: hmm i made some websites but now i don't have live examples to show at the moment. We may talk about it in private though. @AspiringAqib

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21977/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-fabio)

Answer (score 1):

```
div.yotube_video{
border:5px solid red;
}
```

your class name above is yotube_video and you had typed youtube_video

Comment: Your answer is correct, anyway I gave a better answer because i also corrected some other wrong things in the html code.

Comment: ahah..anyway usually i don't write such things in comments :). I just wrote that because you hurried up with "don't forget to accept and upvote the answer" :) anyway sometimes others may provide a more complete answer (it can happen also to me sometimes) so its the person who asked the question that should judge at the end :) . Anyway i'm saying this peacefully :) We just do our best to help others :) @AspiringAqib

Comment: our motto to help others :) go on!

Answer (score 0):

Apply class on your `video` element not on`div`

```
video{
   border:5px solid red;
}
```

Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TFKfr/)

**OR** Other way to do this is as follows

you can provide an `ID` of your `video` element as

```
<div>
        <video id="yotube_video" width="700" height="525" controls="controls" scrolling="no" >
            <source src="video/promo_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
 </div>
```

and apply `CSS` on that `ID` as

```
#yotube_video{
     border:5px solid red;
}
```

Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TFKfr/1/)